# SQL query to find all transactions after the specific part repair

Tags: sql, teradata

My data is similiar to this example which is very huge so idealy require an efficient code. I want to find those transactions after the charger repair for only those customer id which had this repair.

```
    TRANSACTION_ID  REPAIR_DATE CUSTOMER_ID    COMPONENT   LABOR_CODE_DESC Size....
    28289           6/25/2015   AH123        LAPTOP       CHARGER REPAIR   big   
    28235           6/29/2015    AH123       LAPTOP         CHIP REPLACE small
    258978         6/27/2013      HW687      PHONE      TOUCH SCREEN
    28223           6/2/2014     AH123       LAPTOP      BATTERY REPAIR
    215678          7/28/2014       HW687      PHONE         SIM REPAIR
    527808          7/30/2016      HW687      LAPTOP         BATTERY REPAIR
    567976          7/28/2014      HW687      LAPTOP         CHARGER REPAIR  big
    7678698         8/68/2015     AH123        LAPTOP        BATTERY REPAIR
    9987908          5/7/2006       TU890       PHONE      SIM REPAIR
    .....


    OUTPUT
   TRANSACTION_ID  REPAIR_DATE CUSTOMER_ID COMPONENT    LABOR_CODE_DESC ....
   28235           6/29/2015    AH123       LAPTOP         CHIP REPLACE
   7678698         8/68/2015      AH123        LAPTOP        BATTERY REPAIR
   527808          7/30/2016     HW687      LAPTOP          BATTERY REPAIR


   .....

dont need:
  215678          9/7/2014       HW687      PHONE     SIM REPAIR
```

as this has the same date as the charger repair. I tried the following code

```
   SELECT *
   FROM tab
   QUALIFY 
   Max(CASE WHEN LABOR_CODE_DESC = 'CHARGER REPAIR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   Over (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
     ORDER BY REPAIR_DATE
     ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) >= 1
```

By using this I am missing some transactions which happen on the same date as the charger repair date may be beacuse it is sorted by repair date.  I might as well ignore all the transactions that happen same as the charger repair date to avoid this issue. I also want to limit based on size. where can I include that? Please suggest the most efficient way as my table is too huge.

Comment: do you just need all rows after the *first* occurrence of CHARGER REPAIR row for a customer_id?

Comment: Try adding a 2nd sort column to sort first: `ORDER BY REPAIR_DATE, CASE WHEN LABOR_CODE_DESC = 'CHARGER REPAIR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work in Teradata?

```
   SELECT *
   FROM tab
   QUALIFY REPAIR_DATE > Max(CASE WHEN LABOR_CODE_DESC = 'CHARGER REPAIR' THEN REPAIR_DATE
                             END) Over (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
                                        ORDER BY REPAIR_DATE
                                        ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding
                                       );
```

This gets everything starting on the date after the charger repair.